# Regex Conditional Values

Tags: c#, regex

If I have a string like the following that can have two possible values (although the value `JB37` can be variable)

```
String One\r\nString Two\r\n
String One\r\nJB37\r\n
```

And I only want to capture the string if the value following `String One\r\n` does NOT equal `String Two\r\n`, how would I code that in Regex?

So normally without any condition, this is what I want:
`String One\r\n(.+?)\r\n`

Comment: google negative lookahead.

Comment: Try `^String One\\r\\n(?!String Two)([^\\]+)\\r\\n$` [here](https://regex101.com/r/cYYoVq/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex, you may resort to a negative lookahead:

```
String One\r\n(?!String Two(?:\r\n|$))(.*?)(?:\r\n|$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=String+One%5cr%5cn%28%3f!String+Two%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cn%7c%24%29%29%28.*%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%5cn%7c%24%29&i=String+One%0d%0aString+Two%0d%0aString+One%0d%0aJB37%0d%0a)

You may also use `[^\r\n]` instead of `.`:

```
String One\r\n(?!String Two(?:\r\n|$))([^\r\n]*)
```

If you use `RegexOptions.Multiline`, you will also be able to use

```
(?m)String One\r\n(?!String Two\r?$)(.*?)\r?$
```

See [yet another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=String%20One%5Cr%5Cn%28%3F!String%20Two%5Cr%3F%24%29%28.*%3F%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=String%20One%0D%0AString%20Two%0D%0AString%20One%0D%0AJB37%0D%0A&o=m).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - a `RegexOptions.Multiline` option that makes `^` match start of a line and `$` end of line positions
- `String One\r\n` - `String One` text followed with a CRLF line ending
- `(?!String Two\r?$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if immediately to the right of the current location, there is `String Two` at the end of the line
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost occurrence of
- `\r?$` - an optional CR and end of the line (note that in a .NET regex, `$` matches only in front of LF, not CR, in the multiline mode, thus, `\r?` is necessary).

C# demo:

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"(?m)String One\r\n(?!String Two\r?$)(.*?)\r?$");
if (m.Success) 
{
     Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

If CR can be missing, add `?` after each `\r` in the pattern.